# Start another application, then go back to the previous app, and it will change to next page

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like my app could go to the other application by pressing a button by the following code:

```
public void go_other_app() {
        Button going= (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_other);

        going.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name");
                if (launchIntent==null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You haven't installed this app yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    startActivity(launchIntent);

                }
            }

        });

    }
```

Then when the user finishes stuff in this secondary app, he backpress to leave it and go back the previous app. But I would like him to immediately change to another activity without remaining the same activity. I only know the way to start a new activity by:

```
Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),another_activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

So it there a good way to fulfill my task? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

From your `FirstActivity` call the `SecondActivity` using  `startActivityForResult()` method

For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 2404);
```

When user press back button it will notify in `onActivityResult` method of `FirstActivity`.

Write following code for the in firstActivty.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2404) {
        Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),another_activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Please visit below link for more information.
1. [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)
1. [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)
2. [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: it seems doesn't work on me. Does this work when it goes back from another application?

Comment: Have you replace startActivity with startActivityForResult in your onClick() method?

Comment: And also have you override onActivityResult() method in your FirstActivity?

Comment: Ok, but this time, i plug startActivityForResult inside the button,and override onActivityResult() method. When i press the button, it immediately goes to the second activity without going to the other app. It seems that it immediately stimulates onActivityResult() method.